# Is there any way to transfer the content of an external editor in postgresql to query buffer without quitting the editor?

Tags: postgresql, emacs, psql

My environment:

```
OS: Linux CentOS 7 (x86_64)
PostgreSQL version: 10.5
Emacs 26.1
```

I use Emacs as the external editor in postgresql (set in my `EDITOR` environment variable). So whenever I type in psql shell, `\e` it opens Emacs where I can write/modify queries, views, functions, etc.

If I understand correctly, once Emacs is open, when I enter `C-x C-s`, that is, I save and then I quit `C-x C-c`, the content edited in Emacs is transferred to the query buffer to be parsed and executed (assuming it contains semicolon at the end). So basically each time I have to run `\e` then edit, then save and quit the editor to get the job done.

Now, given that I use Emacs for multiple programming languages, I've rather a big init file. As a result, it takes several seconds to start Emacs (both in `-nw` and GUI mode). Obviously this is quite annoying given the number of times that I have to open and quit the editor while I'm using `\e` in psql.

So my question is: Is there any way to let the external editor remain open and continue working with the same editor for further queries and somehow decide to transfer the result to query buffer without needing to quit the editor?

Comment: I would urge you to start using `M-x sql-postgres` to run `psql` inside Emacs, and use a linked `sql-mode` buffer to edit queries and send them to the psql buffer.

Comment: I know M-x sql-postgres, but does it actually call psql or it is just a shell developped for Emacs to simulate psql? Also what do you mean by "linked" sql-mode?

Comment: Yes, it runs and interacts with a `psql` process; and maybe https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlQueryBuffer will help you with your second question.

Comment: You may also find https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18403/454 useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `emacsclient` instead of `emacs`.  I have a script at `~/bin/editor`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec emacsclient -c -a '' "$@"
```

And then I set `export EDITOR=$HOME/bin/editor` in my `~/.bashrc`.

The upshot is you only start Emacs once, and every time you run `$EDITOR`, it just attaches to the same Emacs session.

Also, I do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") #'delete-frame)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-S-c") #'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

so `C-x C-c` just deletes the frame instead of killing Emacs.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks. I voted up but apparently doesn't show given that I don't still have enough points. This solved my problem. It seems that once the Emacs daemon is running, the two key bindings you provided above, are no longer necessary and C-x C-c closes the client frame but not the Emacs core running as daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the query to a temporary file, for example `/tmp/q.sql` and run `\i /tmp/q.sql` from psql multiple times from a second terminal.